# setState() in Reactjs updating multiple properties instead of one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I update 'classProficienciesChoices' in my state using setState() it is updating not only that property, but also where I derived the 'classProficienciesChoices' info from in the 'classSelected' property, AND ALSO from where I derived the classSelected info from in the 'classesInfo' property.

The same function I update 'classProficienciesChoices' I also update 'classProficiencies', and it updates properly in the one property I tell it to, and not the elements where the information was derived from.

Any insight would be helpful. The Create component has other components nested and none of them have state and only use props passed. There are navigation, selection, and information display components nested.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Create from './Create'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const url = 'http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/';

        fetch(url + 'classes')
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => { this.setState({ classes: result, }, this.getInfo(result)) });
    }

    state = {
        classes: {}, //assigned value from API call in constructor
        classesInfo: [], //assigned value from API call in getInfo()
        classSelected: {}, //assigned a value derived from classInfo in displayClassInfo()
        classProficiencies: [],   //assigned a value derived from classSelected in setStartingProficiencies()
        classProficienciesChoices: [],  //assigned a value derived from classSelected in setStartingProficiencies()
    } 

    getInfo(data) {
        let info = []
        const url = 'http://www.dnd5eapi.co'
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            fetch(url + data.results[i].url)
                .then(result => result.json())
                .then(result => info.push(result))
        }
        this.setState({ classesInfo: info, })
        }
    }

    setStartingProficiencies(chosenClass) {

        const profs = chosenClass.proficiencies.map((prof) => {
            return prof;
        });
        const proChoice = chosenClass.proficiency_choices.map((choices) => {
            return choices;
        });

        this.setState({ classProficiencies: profs, classProficienciesChoices: proChoice, });        
    } 

    addProficiency = (proficiencyName) => { 
        const { classProficienciesChoices } = this.state
        // classProficienciesChoices: [
        //        { choose: 2, type: 'proficiencies', from: [{ name: 'someName', url: 'someUrl' }, { name: 'someName', url: 'someUrl' }] },
        //          ]
        // different classes have more objects in the parent array

        let newChoiceArray = classProficienciesChoices.map((choices) => {
            return choices
        })

        for (var i = 0; i < newChoiceArray.length; i++) { 
            for (var j = 0; j < newChoiceArray[i].from.length; j++) {
                if (newChoiceArray[i].from[j].name === proficiencyName) {

                    let newChoices = newChoiceArray[i].from.filter(function (proficiency) { return proficiency.name !== pIndex })
                    let newProficiency = newChoiceArray[i].from.filter(function (proficiency) { return proficiency.name === pIndex })

                    newChoiceArray[i].from = newChoices //I think this is the problem

                    this.setState(state => ({
                        classProficiencies: [...state.classProficiencies, newProficiency[0]],
                        proficienciesChoices: newChoiceArray,
                    }))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    displayClassInfo = index => {
        const { classesInfo } = this.state
        for (let i = 0; i < classesInfo.length; i++) {
            if (classesInfo[i].index === index) {
                const classSelected = classesInfo.filter(function (cClass) { return cClass.name === classesInfo[i].name })
                this.setState({ classSelected: classSelected[0], isClassSelected: true }, this.setStartingProficiencies(classSelected[0]),)
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    render() {

        const { classes, classesInfo, classSelected, isClassSelected, classProficiencies, classProficienciesChoices } = this.state

        return (<Create classes={classes} classesInfo={classesInfo} displayClassInfo={this.displayClassInfo} classSelected={classSelected} isClassSelected={isClassSelected} category='classes' classProficiencies={classProficiencies} classProficienciesChoices={classProficienciesChoices} addProficiency={this.addProficiency} />);

    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Hello Jasper, and welcome! The first issue I see off the bat is that your seem to be doing some type of asynchronous work in `getInfo()` without waiting for all the responses to return before using `setState`

Comment: Hi @DerekPollard I do not believe that lack of information is the problem, when the problem from above occurs. I do get undefined errors every so often, which is likely due to what you have stated, but when everything is good and all the information is present the problem occurs. What do you suggest to help with that delay?

Answer (score 0):

You call setState four times, of course it will update the state multiple times.

Comment: Yes, I do call setState() multiple times, in different functions. The problem is when I call setState on that one particular property, it updates on two other properties that I am not calling setState() on.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!! Stumbled across turning the array into a string and then back. It breaks the reference and creates an entirely new array. Reference type got me.

```
setStartingProficiencies(chosenClass) {

        const proficiencies = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chosenClass.proficiencies))
        const proficienciesChoices = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chosenClass.proficiency_choices))    

        this.setState({ classProficiencies: proficiencies, classProficienciesChoices: proficienciesChoices, });

    }
```